# How do i write an applescript application from terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I want to write an applescript application from terminal. So far I have been able to write an .scpt file but that is not enough. I need to convert it to an applescript application that can then be opened and run. I know how to do this using the GUI but for various reasons I need to do it from terminal. Any ideas on any way to do this?

Comment: RTM- `osacompile`. `apropos` can be your best friend.

Comment: Can you explain how to use those things?

Answer (score 1):

To make apple scripts executable from terminal, you may define `osascript` in [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript
say "Hello World!"
```

Make it executable, and just run it:

```
./AppleScriptTest.applescript
```